# Ruby Version Manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rvm

I'm new to Ruby and currently using Windows 10. I'm facing difficulty installing RVM. Since I work on different projects with varying Ruby versions, I want to use RVM to manage them easily. Currently, I find myself frequently changing the system variable path whenever I switch between projects. Could you please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Im have installed the **RVM** but it shows something like this
'rvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ruby on Rails 4 is no longer supported or maintained. You should not be using it.

Comment: Probably you need to set up your PATH variable to include wherever rvm is installed.

Answer (score 0):

RVM supports most UNIX like systems and Windows. The basic requirements are bash, curl, gpg2 and overall GNU version of tools - but RVM tries to autodetect it and install anything that is needed.

Use WSL(Windows Subsystem For Linux) - https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/wsl/install

from: https://rvm.io/rvm/install

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y gnupg2

gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

rvm install <ruby version>

rvm list

rvm use <ruby version>
```